# Разбор словосочетания по типу связей

Tags: словосочетания

```
Он был далеко за углом
```

Какой тип имеет словосочетание `далеко за углом` - наречное или именное?
Какая связь в этом словосочетании - примыкание или падежное примыкание?
Какое сказуемое в предложении?